# "Revision History" link

Tags: discussion, feature-request, revision-history

Rather than having the current system, where in a question or answer the revision history link is the "Edited  ago" text, wouldn't it be less confusing to add a link called "Revisions" or "Revision History" to the line of links that shows up on a question (the links for link, edit, flag, and so on.)?

Personally, I find having the revisions link under that line of text stating the time since the last edit too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat obscure, but then, so are revisions.

Once learned (and I agree, it has to be learned) it is not a difficult convention to follow, IMHO.

Generally we're not a fan of arbitrarily adding more links to the page in the name of "Don't Make Me Think"; there is a lot to be said for having just the most important things as obvious links.